# Return download URL from nested firebase function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I used a local variable to set a value from firebase function but it doesn't work. I return URL following this code but I don't know how to read firebase object:

```jsx
export var downloadFile = (folderName, fileName) => {
  // Create a reference to the file we want to download
  var starsRef = storageRef.child(`${folderName}/${fileName}`);


  // Get the download URL
return  starsRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    // Insert url into an <img> tag to "download"
    return url
  })

}
```

The output will be like this:
[image]

How can I return URL or How can I read firebase object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firebase doc said

> You can get the download URL for a file by calling the getDownloadURL() method on a storage reference.

So the object is a complete file URL und you can return it to a  tag in this example.
Look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

But you are returning the promise of it and not the url itself.

If you are logging the url inside the promise callback it should display it.